# all TARs not extracting

Tags: 16.04, nginx, tar, extract, gzip

Link to file: http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz

so, i'm trying to install nginx with the rtmp module and when I go to extract the nginx source from the tar.gz i get an error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

tar: Child returned status 1

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

My input: `tar zxf nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz`

output of "file nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz": `nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines`

Update: this is happening with every Tar file. not just nginx

Comment: Please provide a direct link to a file that doesn't work.

Comment: http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz

Comment: That should work... Please edit your question to add the output of `file nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz` (and also the link while you're at it).

Comment: i've added the link and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run tar without specifying the "z" part.

tar xvf nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz

Also, try to cat the file. It seems like you're not receiving the correct file.

```
dak@dak-tp:~/Downloads$ file nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz 
nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Tue Nov 15 15:11:52 2016, from Unix
dak@dak-tp:~/Downloads$ md5sum nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz 
4e29a07a7c74376fa032e5af0d1c5369  nginx-1.11.6.tar.gz
```

Comment: 'gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now'
and here's the cat: http://pastebin.com/EchkSYwC

Comment: Well there you have it. Your download was blocked by some weird product made by Lightspeed Systems. Read the paste yourself... you're not getting a gzipped tar file, but rather a html page.

Comment: Yep, thanks so much. I never considered reading the file that was downloaded... feel kinda dumb lol